# how $\int_a ^ b |f'(x)|$ gives the length of the arc of the contour $f$ : $(f(x) : x \in [a , b])$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I got to know that $\int_a ^ b |f'(x)|$ gives the length of any contour. Where $f(x)$ is a piece-wise differentiable function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R^2$. I was reading complex integral . Can anyone please enlighten me how it is ? I understand for the functions whose Domain and Range are $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is the length of the arc $\{f(x): a\leq x \leq b\}$ .

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Proof of Arc-Length Formula in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616682/proof-of-arc-length-formula-in-mathbbrn).

Answer (score 2):

What is the length of a curve?

Let $a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n = b$ a partition of $[a,b]$

An approximation of the length can be

$Len(f) \approx \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x_i+1)-f(x_i)|$

You can see that when at the limit where the partition is delicate enough you get

$Len(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|f(x_i+1)-f(x_i)|=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Delta x_i|\frac{f(x_i+1)-f(x_i)}{\Delta x_i}|\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow \infty} = \int_a^b|f'(x)|dx$

Thats the general idea

Comment: I understand this...But what will happen for the general case?@ItamarShmelo

Comment: Define the general case?

Comment: Yea tell me for the case $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$  @ItamarShmelo

Comment: $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$  then $Len(f)=\int \sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt$ If you are using the euclidian norm